# If score is higher than 5 then

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

So if my score is higher than 5 then gotoSceneA elseif gotoSceneB.
But I am getting this error:

```
game.lua:439: unexpected symbol near '..'*
```

If i remove the `..` I get:

```
game.lua:443: 'then' expected near 'end'
```

My code:

```
if .. score > 5 then
    storyboard.gotoScene("bonus", "fade", 400)
elseif
    storyboard.gotoScene("gameover", "fade", 400)
end
end
```

Comment: Please change `elseif` to `else`. Also, you should remove the `..`.

Comment: Also, You should remove last line with an `end`.
You don't need multiple ends for one `if then/else` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lua
if score > 1000 then
    storyboard.gotoScene("bonus", "fade", 400)
else
    storyboard.gotoScene("gameover", "fade", 400)
end
```